# Find out if firm enters or leaves industries over time

Tags: time-series, stata, panel-data

I have a data set with information about firms:

```
clear
input firm_id str6 industry int fyear int
1084    7372    2010
1084    7375    2010
1084    7372    2011
1084    7375    2011
1084    7372    2012
1084    7375    2012
1084    7372    2013
1084    7375    2013
1084    7372    2014
1084    7375    2014
1094    2865    2002
1094    2879    2002
1094    5122    2002
1094    5169    2002
1094    2865    2003
1094    2879    2003
1094    5122    2003
1094    5169    2003
1094    2865    2004
1094    2879    2004
1094    5122    2004
1094    5169    2004
1094    2865    2005
1094    2879    2005
1094    5122    2005
1094    5169    2005
1094    2865    2006
1094    2879    2006
1094    5122    2006
1094    5169    2006
1094    2865    2007
1094    2879    2007
1094    5169    2007
1094    2865    2008
1094    2879    2008
end
```

Aside from a `firm_id` it includes information about which industries the firm is active in a given year.

How can I find how many industries a firm left and entered, in a given year?

I know that I could do this by writing a "loop in a loop" that looks at every individual observation and checks if the same `firm_id` and `industry` combination exists for `year`+1. But my data set is large, so that would be extremely inefficient.

I also contemplated solutions using `reshape wide`, but could not find a solution to my problem either (and of course this creates an extremely large number of variables and is not efficient either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to generate a single observation for each firm with the number of industries a firm enters and exits in each year, I believe the following code should work.  The variables `enter` and `leave` indicate (respectively) if a firm enters or exists the industry in a given observation.  Using a `foreach` loop over the years in the data you can then generate each of the variables indicating whether the firm enters or exits each year.

```
bys firm_id industry (fyear): gen prevyear = fyear[_n-1]
gen yrdifpast = fyear - prevyear
gen enter = yrdifpast > 1

bys firm_id industry (fyear): gen nextyear = fyear[_n+1]
gen yrdiffuture = nextyear - fyear
gen leave = yrdiffuture > 1

levelsof fyear, local(years)
foreach yr of local years {
    gen in_`yr'  = fyear==`yr'&enter==1
    gen out_`yr' = fyear==`yr'&leave==1
}

collapse (sum) in_* out_*, by(firm_id)

list
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1. | firm_id | in_2002 | in_2003 | in_2004 | in_2005  | in_2006  | in_2007  | in_2008  | in_2010  |
     |    1084 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0  |       0  |       0  |       0  |       2  |
     |---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------|
     | in_2011 | in_2012 | in_2013 | in_2014 | out_2002 | out_2003 | out_2004 | out_2005 | out_2006 |
     |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |  out_2007  |  out_2008  |  out_2010  |  out_2011   |  out_2012   |  out_2013   |  out_2014   |
     |         0  |         0  |         0  |         0   |         0   |         0   |         2   |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  2. | firm_id | in_2002 | in_2003 | in_2004 | in_2005  | in_2006  | in_2007  | in_2008  | in_2010  |
     |    1094 |       4 |       0 |       0 |       0  |       0  |       0  |       0  |       0  |
     |---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------|
     | in_2011 | in_2012 | in_2013 | in_2014 | out_2002 | out_2003 | out_2004 | out_2005 | out_2006 |
     |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |  out_2007  |  out_2008  |  out_2010  |  out_2011   |  out_2012   |  out_2013   |  out_2014   |
     |         1  |         2  |         0  |         0   |         0   |         0   |         0   |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see that any loops are needed here. But what are needed are precise and explicit rules. Here a firm enters an industry whenever its first year on record is after the first year in the dataset and a firm leaves whenever its last year on record is before the last year in the dataset. Further, a firm leaves the industry if the next year on record is more than a year later, and a firm enters the industry if the previous year on record is more than a year previously. That allows leaving and re-entering, unlikely though such changes may be.

```
summarize fyear, meanonly 
local first = r(min) 
local last = r(max)     
bysort firm_id industry (fyear) : generate enter = (fyear > `first') if _n == 1 
by firm_id industry : replace enter = (fyear - fyear[_n-1]) > 1 if _n > 1    
by firm_id industry : generate leave = fyear < `last' if _n == _N 
by firm_id industry : replace leave = (fyear[_n+1] - fyear) > 1 if _n < _N 

table fyear firm_id, c(sum enter sum leave)
```